# Calculating NTC temperature on Controllino Maxi Automation yields incorrect temperature

Tags: arduino, thermistor, controllino

I'm using the analog input on the Controllino Maxi Automation to determine the temperature of a 10K NTC thermistor. At first we thought it was a self heating issue given that with 24V the current through the NTC would make that issue more prevalent.

To verify, I connected the Controllino to only my laptop and used the pin headers to hookup the NTC and series resistor to as shown below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBGt9k.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Following the advice in [my previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/560551/what-does-a-scaling-factor-mean-for-an-adc/560567?noredirect=1#comment1462479_560567) I oversampled the voltage to help with noise and attempted to calculate the temperature

```
#include <Controllino.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
// Thermistor Example #3 from the Adafruit Learning System guide on Thermistors 
// https://learn.adafruit.com/thermistor/overview by Limor Fried, Adafruit Industries
// MIT License - please keep attribution and consider buying parts from Adafruit
 
// which analog pin to connect
#define THERMISTORPIN A0         
// resistance at 25 degrees C
#define THERMISTORNOMINAL 10000      
// temp. for nominal resistance (almost always 25 C)
#define TEMPERATURENOMINAL 25  
// how many samples to take and average, more takes longer
// but is more 'smooth'
#define NUMSAMPLES 255
// The beta coefficient of the thermistor (usually 3000-4000)
#define BCOEFFICIENT 3892 // datasheet - https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/240/Littelfuse_Thermistor_Probes_Assemblies_Threaded_U-1372560.pdf
// the value of the 'other' resistor
#define SERIESRESISTOR 9760    
 
int samples[NUMSAMPLES];
 
void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(921600);
}
 
void loop(void) {
  uint8_t i;
  float average;
  long long int values= 0;
  // take N samples in a row, with a slight delay
  for (i=0; i< NUMSAMPLES; i++) {
   values += analogRead(THERMISTORPIN);
   delay(1);
  }
  
  average = (float)values / NUMSAMPLES;
 
  Serial.print("Average analog reading "); 
  Serial.print(average);
  
  // convert the value to resistance
  average = 1023 / average - 1;
  average = SERIESRESISTOR / average;
  Serial.print(" Thermistor resistance "); 
  Serial.print(average);
  
  float steinhart;
  steinhart = average / THERMISTORNOMINAL;     // (R/Ro)
  steinhart = log(steinhart);                  // ln(R/Ro)
  steinhart /= BCOEFFICIENT;                   // 1/B * ln(R/Ro)
  steinhart += 1.0 / (TEMPERATURENOMINAL + 273.15); // + (1/To)
  steinhart = 1.0 / steinhart;                 // Invert
  steinhart -= 273.15;                         // convert absolute temp to C
  
  Serial.print(" Temperature "); 
  Serial.print(steinhart);
  Serial.println(" *C");
  
  delay(1000);
}
```

That yielded the below results, I should point out the USB voltage is at 4.5V and the actual thermistor resistance (measured outside of the circuit) is 11.63k

```
Average analog reading 369.96 Thermistor resistance 5529.25 Temperature 39.18 *C
Average analog reading 369.95 Thermistor resistance 5529.07 Temperature 39.18 *C
Average analog reading 369.96 Thermistor resistance 5529.25 Temperature 39.18 *C
Average analog reading 369.94 Thermistor resistance 5528.70 Temperature 39.18 *C
Average analog reading 369.96 Thermistor resistance 5529.25 Temperature 39.18 *C
```

Which is definitely wrong, my room temperature atm is around 17-20C and the physically measured voltage across the thermistor is 1.8V

[Just for quick reference](https://www.controllino.com/tutorials/#1539865917417-ebd27284-162b), the pot here is replaced with R1 and the NTC in series and there's no external power supply, just the USB attached.

[image]

Comment: Replace the sensor with a 1% 10K resistor and check the reading. Likewise with a lower resistance to simulate something near the top of your range.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I don't have a 1% 10K  at the moment, can I use a %5 10K and measure the actual resistance of it?

Comment: Sure, just measure the resistances with just about any working multimeter and make sure that your resistance reading matches closely enough. But try to cover the range of the sensor.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, before we move further. I replaced the NTC with a 9.78k resistor and measured a voltage of 1.7V across it. That, is wrong, by calculation it's supposed to be 2.2V with 4.5V at the top.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I used a USB breakout and measured a Vcc of 5.1. I replaced the voltage divider's supply with that 5.1 and got 2.5V across the 9.78K. Which makes the above result with the Controllino's supply, all the more confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked around the Controlino website, and found an [instruction manual.](https://www.controllino.biz/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/CONTROLLINO-Instruction-Manual.pdf)

It mentions an automatically switched voltage divider:

> CONTROLLINO uses an automatic voltage divider internally which is controlled over the supply voltage. Depending on the supply voltage the divider is switched to the right value.

I can't find anything that mentions the input impedance of the analog inputs.  If they've just plopped in a voltage divider without any kind of buffering, then the input impedance could be rather low.  That would explain the low reading - the divider is basically another resistor in parallel with the NTC.

If that's the case, then you would need an op-amp as a buffer between the NTC and the analog input.

You can find out if they've just put a couple of resistors in as a voltage divider by doing the following:

1. Connect 5V to the analog input - straight to it, no resistors.
2. Have the Controllduino print out the ADC value.
3. Now put about a 5k resistor between the 5V and the analog input.
4. Print out the ADC value again.

The values for (2) and (4) should be very close together if the input is buffered.

If the values differ significantly (say 1/3 or more,) then the Controllduino "designers" put in a voltage divider without a buffer and you'll have buffer the NTC yourself.

Comment: I think you're right. I just had a barebones voltage divider setup and as soon as I connected the controllino A0 input, it dropped by 0.6V. Should I continue with the rest of the experiment?

Comment: It sounds like you have your answer.  It shouldn't have dropped much, but it did.  You'll need  to use a non inverting op-amp buffer between the NTC and A0.

Comment: This might get removed because it's not adding value to the question. But I really appreciate your assist on this one!